# Does "PayPal Here" send IPN notifications?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to figure out if the PayPal Here iOS app sends IPN notifications, and I'd rather not try it with a real credit card to find out. My business account with PayPal is registered to receive IPN notifications for all transactions, but I'm not sure if that applies to PayPal Here or just the "classic" APIs.

Answer (score 2):

It applies to PayPal Here. 
Here's a sample IPN:

```
mc_gross=1.10
protection_eligibility=Ineligible
payer_id=XXXXX
tax=0.00
payment_date=10%3A56%3A10+Mar+05%2C+2013+PST
cc_input_method=Swipe
payment_status=Completed
payment_method=credit_card
invoice_id=XXXX-XXX
geolocation=XX.37588990114492+-XX1.921036809166
charset=ISO-8859-1
first_name=XXXX
mc_fee=0.03
notify_version=3.7
custom=
payer_status=unverified
business=xxxxx%40hotmail.com
quantity=1
verify_sign=A.7n6Acd75CB8FdbeZyRGF.BoVPlAh1DpDw5NsPgku3fVBbOvyXeZP64
discount_amount=0.00
txn_id=XXXXCX
payment_type=instant
last_name=XXXXX
receiver_email=XXXXXX%40hotmail.com
payment_fee=0.03
receiver_id=XXXXXXX
txn_type=paypal_here
item_name=
buyer_signature=yes
mc_currency=USD
item_number=
residence_country=US
receipt_id=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX
handling_amount=0.00
transaction_subject=
invoice_number=XXXXXX
payment_gross=1.10
shipping=0.00
ipn_track_id=abcdefg
```

Comment: You Xed out the invoice_number.  Was that YOUR custom invoice number returned there, or is that the PayPal invoice number?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Here DOES send IPN, if you have IPN configured in your account settings. Unfortunately, it doesn't send the CUSTOM or ITEM_NAME, or ITEM_NUMBER variables, at this time. The variables Dennis shared above are the ones I receive, but it would be cool if some of the custom variables were present, too.

Comment: When using the general transaction method with the PayPal Here app, they provide a `Enter a description (optional)` field.  It's a shame this isn't simply passed through as the CUSTOM or ITEM_NAME IPN variable.

Comment: It looks like it's returning an invoice_number.  Did you ever test to see if GetInvoiceDetails would then work with that invoice number?  It would include itemized details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official statement but as most payments trigger send a message to your IPN PayPal Here should do it too.

Comment: I have seen these go through, but annoyingly theres very little customer data, so its not as useful as a regular IPN message

Answer (score 0):

I asked Paypal this very question and was told "No", it will not send IPN notifications.  It is a completely different type of payment since it is a "Card Present" transaction.  It will show in your history as a "mobile payment".  Again, that is what Paypal told me.  They also said that mobile payments are very new for them so they are continuing to develop the APIs and such for that product.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PayPal does send an IPN, however it doesn't provide much information about the payer or the individual items purchased.

[@Andrew Angell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188826/andrew-angell)
Sorry, I can't reply to your comment (not enough points). The invoice number is generated by PayPal. You can do a call to the REST API ([GET /v1/invoicing/invoices/](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#retrieve-an-invoice)) on that invoice ID to get additional information about the payer, and it also returns each item ordered (name, cost, currency).

If you're using the REST API to get the invoice, don't forget to add the scope for "Invoices" on your PayPal developer REST API apps page!

I also tried using GetTransactionDetails (classic API), but it doesn't return any useful information (specifically the items ordered and the payer's email). Also tried ["GET /v1/payments/sale/"](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#look-up-a-sale) with the IPN's transaction_id, but forgot to read that it only returns sales created through the REST API.

Hope this helps!